# setattr() usage in this line

Tags: python, kivy, encapsulation

I got this code from somewhere but I don't understand this line of it:

`Dropdown.bind(on_select = lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))`

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require("1.9.2")
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
Dropdown = DropDown()
# creating an object out of a function
for i in range(1, 11):
    button = Button(text="Button Number " + str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    # 10 buttons with different numbers created
    button.bind(on_release=lambda button: Dropdown.select(button.text))
    # Dropdown is a function so that's why we're using Dropdown and not mainbutton that has no attribute 'select'
    # buttons bind to dropdown and if they're selected their text goes on dropdown main button
    # lambda for WHENEVER button is pressed, then when it's released something happens
    Dropdown.add_widget(button)
    # means that it is added on the layout and screen

mainbutton = Button(text="Select A Button", size_hint=(None, None), pos=(350, 300))

mainbutton.bind(on_release = Dropdown.open)
# when button is pressed and then it's released, dropdown menu opens
Dropdown.bind(on_select = lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
# 
runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

Comment: Even that one line has lots of parts to it. There must be some parts you do understand. Please explain those parts and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: I don't understand, that's why I'm asking but I think I know the bind part

Comment: And also the `on_select = ` part. You know that because `mainbutton.bind()` has something similar.

Comment: yea only those parts

Comment: Ok, so its `lambda` you've never come across. Did you do a search on that before posting your question?

Comment: yes i know that it's for functions. lemme tell you, I don't know about ```instance``` , ```x``` , ```setattr``` and the items inside it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't know `kivy` and its not clear from the documentation that I can find, but it seems to me that `kivy` produces events internally and you can hook into them by binding a function of your own (a `lambda` in this case) to that event.

So when the `on_select` event occurs, a function is called with two parameters. These are the `instance, x` parts. Whatever calls your function supplies two parameters: `instance` being the dropdown instance, and `x` being the data selected. Your `lambda` then runs the expression: `setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x)` which I take to mean the same as `mainbutton.text = x`.